# String comparison isn't working

Tags: javascript

The hash variable and the mycookie variable are the same but I don't get the message. What am I missing here?

```
  var hash= "f353fbe0acb344e5cc6240daef41de27";
  if (hash ==  <?php echo $_COOKIE[mycookie]; ?>) var text = "the same";
  document.write(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a string so you need to quote it:

```
if (hash ==  "<?php echo $_COOKIE[mycookie]; ?>") var text = "the same";
```

Beware that the cookie content can be set by the user, so you need to ensure you don't leave an XSS hole open.

A better way would be to JSON encode it (which will add the quotes):

```
if (hash ==  <?php echo json_encode($_COOKIE[mycookie]); ?>) var text = "the same";
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that you are trying to debug JavaScript without:

- Looking at the JavaScript error console *or*
- Looking at the JavaScript (you are looking at PHP).

Unless your cookie *value* contains quote marks (which I doubt), you are comparing `hash` to an undeclared variable.

Convert the PHP variable to a JavaScript literal with `json_encode`:

```
hash ==  <?php echo json_encode($_COOKIE[mycookie]); ?>
```

Note that this will correctly escape any characters that aren't allowed (raw) in a JS string literal (such as quotes, backslashes and new lines) (which just surrounding the PHP with `"` character wouldn't do).